# What is different between 'self.fn.apply(self, message)' and 'self.fn(message)', and why use the first way?

Tags: javascript, function

I always find some code like that`newPromise.promiseDispatch.apply(newPromise, message)`, I do not understand why not use `newPromise.promiseDispathch(message)`

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference is that [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects a `this` binding and array of arguments, instead of listing each argument individually with the parens call.

For example, if `foo.bar = (...args) => console.log(args)`, then calling `foo.bar.apply(foo, [1, 2, 3])` will log `1, 2, 3` (i.e., three separate arguments for each element of the array) and `foo.bar([1, 2, 3])` will log `[1, 2, 3]` (the array object as a single argument).

The [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method on functions is more equivalent to calling with parens, since it takes each argument individually. The forms `foo.bar.call(foo, 1, 2, 3)` and `foo.bar(1, 2, 3)` are equivalent.

It is common to see either method used when the passed scope does not match the object (`foo.bar.call(baz, ...)`), since this provides dynamic scoping on methods that have not been previously bound. You'll also see `apply` used when arguments are taken as or gathered into an array, especially in logging and such (`let args = [clazz, level, timestamp, ...msg]; logger.apply(this, args);`).

Comment: There is no "dynamic scoping" in ECMAScript.

Comment: and what is different between  'newPromise.promiseDispatch.call(newPromise, message)'  and 'newPromise.promiseDispathch(message)'